# How to make a button in html that submits a google search with options?

Tags: javascript, html, search, button

I can make a button that goes to google but when I put search options it doesn't work.

Basically I am trying to submit a search phrase to google like this:
search items site:www.website.com OR site:www.website2.com

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/

I found it very useful while I was writing google-dork generating programs.